# How to activate the QR code puzzles?

Tags: ps4, watch-dogs

I've found several QR code pieces, and can't figure out what I'm supposed to do with them.  The in-game help isn't clear, it just says you need to *find a camera to align the sections of a QR code and then hold a button to scan it and download the audio log*.

So when I'm near the QR code pieces, I hack a camera and zoom in on them, but there's no way to capture them or *align* them.  Obviously somebody's got to have figured this out, what am I missing?

Comment: I've never actually played the game, but have you tried using a smartphone camera with a QR code reader app?

Comment: It's a classic perspective puzzle. There's an image (in this case the QR code) which doesn't make much sense, until you find a place, from which the image *does* make sense. "Align" here means you have to find the place, from which the QR code actually looks like a complete QR code. It's similar to the question mark images scattered in Batman Arkham Asylum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Aligning* in this case means to find the camera whose perspective causes the QR code to form a complete image. (I.e., an unbroken square.)

Once you find this spot the game will prompt you to scan the code.

If you don't mind spoilers, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHYLkPuBLnY&feature=youtu.be&t=13m12s) is a video of this in action.

Comment: Wow, your one sentence should have been the game's help for this puzzle.  Thanks!